# windows fopen fails randomly with permission denied

Tags: c, windows, winapi, fopen, permission-denied

I'm trying to read and write to files in the c drive of my computer. The `fopen()` function fails randomly.

```
FILE *fp = fopen(strIn, "r");
if(fp == NULL){
    printf("Error: %d (%s)\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    getchar();
}
```

This call sometimes succeeds and sometimes fails. Cannot predict why. I'm always running it in admin mode. Whether this could be windows issue?
The error message it get is error `-13 , permission denied`. I have tried calling

```
_chmod(outFile , _S_IREAD);
```

and checked the return value and then called `fopen()`. The `fopen()` failed again.

Comment: `strerror` and errno isn't best strategy to check Windows error. Try [`GetLastError()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Also, [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) may helpful to catch such errors.

Comment: What is in `strIn` ? is it always the same filename ? Is it an absolute or a relative filename ? In the latter case the default directory ([SetCurrentDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [GetCurrentDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934(v=vs.85).aspx) functions) may be the cause.

Comment: Is there a Anti-Virus program running?

Comment: Why do you need to run elevated? Or are you just trying things at random?